# Unit Testing in Test Explorer says "not run" despite producing no errors and only warning messages

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Beginner here - I am trying to test the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PersonCreator
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; } = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
        public double Height { get; set; } = 0.0;
        public Boolean IsMarried { get; set; } = false;
        public int NoOfChildren { get; set; } = 0;

        public Person(string name, DateTime birthdate, double height, Boolean isMarried, int noOfChildren)
        {
            this.Name = name;   
            this.BirthDate = birthdate;
            this.Height = height;
            this.IsMarried = isMarried;
            this.NoOfChildren = noOfChildren;
        }

        public string MakeTitle()
        {
            string title = ($"{Name};{BirthDate};{Height};{IsMarried};{NoOfChildren}");
            return title;
        }
    }
}
```

With the following unit test:

```
using PersonCreator;
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckPersonConstructor()
    {
        // #### ARRANGE ####
        Person person = new Person("John Doe", new DateTime(1975, 8, 24), 175.9, true, 3);

        // #### ACT ####
        string title = person.MakeTitle();

        // #### ASSERT ####
        Assert.AreEqual("John Doe;24-08-1975 00:00:00;175,9;True;3", title);


       }
}
```

Running the Test Explorer in Visual Studio simply says "1 not run test" and running "dotnet test" provides the following errors:
[image]

What could be the issue for the test not running and the warning messages?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved, updated the NuGet packages

EDIT: Included the picture of the packages.
[image]

Comment: which nuget package was it?

Comment: @SiddharthDinesh Updated the answer, please see the attached picture for reference for the updated packages - should be those three